# Meaning of "heavy odds stacked against him" in a sentence

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

I cannot understand the meaning of this sentence:

Would he be able to save his friend when heavy odds are stacked against him?

Does it mean that would he be able to save his friend when the problems get bigger/more than expected?

Could someone explain it in simple words?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/odds%20are%20stacked%20against%20%28someone%29#:~:text=idiom-,Definition%20of%20odds%20are%20stacked%20against%20(someone),odds%20are%20stacked%20against%20her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"odds", in this case, refers to probability.  "heavy odds" would indicate that there is a very large or very small probability.  "stacked against" clarifies that only a very small probability exists for success.

"odds" is originally a betting term.  A horse may be racing with "25 to 1 odds", meaning that a $2 bet placed on the horse will pay $50.  It also means that people perceive that the horse has about a 1 in 25 chance of winning the race.  Horse racing was very popular in the 1930s (US at least) and the word "odds" crossed into common language.